# Complex Interpolation and Intersection

Tags: interpolation-theory

Does it hold 
$$[X \cap Y, X \cap Z]_\theta = X \cap [Y,Z]_\theta$$
where $X,Y,Z$ are suitable spaces and $[\cdot,\cdot]_\theta $ denotes the complex interpolation functor of order $\theta \in [0,1]$. The inclusion $\subseteq$ follows directly by the definition. However, I do not see wether the reverse inclusion holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is not true in general. You can take $X=H^1(\Omega), Y=L^2(\Omega), Z=H^2(\Omega)$ and $\theta=1/2$ to get two different spaces.

Maybe the result you are looking for is **Theorem 13.1** of section **13. Intersection Interpolation** in

> J.-L. Lions and E. Magenes, Non-homogeneous boundary value problems and applications, Vol. 1, Springer-Verlag (1972).

**Edit 1:** I found (by chance) a sufficient condition which gives the result you asked for in the following paper, see **pp. 3**, and **Lemma 3.4** (with the comments just before):

> [C L. Fefferman, K W. Hajduk, J C. Robinson, Simultaneous approximation in Lebesgue and Sobolev norms via eigenspaces. Preprint (2019).](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332300690_Simultaneous_approximation_in_Lebesgue_and_Sobolev_norms_via_eigenspaces)

Comment: Thank you. Do you know wether the situation changes when replacing complex with real Interpolation?

Comment: @Rooibos I don't think so, because complex and real interpolations coincide in Hilbert spaces for $p=2$.